# Convert Bayer RGGB to CV iplimage (RGB)

Tags: c++, opencv, converters, mat, iplimage

currently I'm trying to convert the Bayer RGGB data to an iplimage. 
I thought cvtColor might work but it requires "mat" instead of iplimage.

```
cvtColor(img->imageData, tmpimageData, CV_BayerBG2BGR, 0);
```

Is there a workaround, maybe you can convert Bayer RGGB to mat and then convert mat to iplimage? I'm really stuck with this problem, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV can easily convert between Mat and Iplimage.
E.g., if `img` is an `IplImage*`:

```
Mat m(img);
Mat result;
cvtColor(m, result, CV_BayerBG2BGR, 0);
IplImage ipl_result  = IplImage(result);
```

See [Mat::Mat(const IplImage* img, bool copyData=false)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mat) and [Mat::operator IplImage()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-operator-iplimage)

Comment: Well that's quite usefull ^^
I guess i can use img again, and don't need to create the new IplImage "ipl_result"!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I didn't figure out why `cvtColor` didn't work, but nonetheless I found a why to convert BayerRGGB to RGB with my SDK.

It turned out that the matrix-vision sdk I was working with provided a built in solution. 
The first thing I needed to do was to change `PixelFormat` to BayerRG8 in order to get 8 bit Image resolution. After that, I managed to decode Bayer RGGB to RGB by writing idpfRGB888Packed into `ImageDestination.pixelFormat`.

Also, I was able to do my conversion in a very primitive way, which also got the job done but required way too much cpu time. 
I looped my `imageData` array and took out every fourth pixel.

```
for (int count_small = 0, count_large = 0; count_large < 1000; count_small += 3, count_large +=4)
{
  dest[count_small] = source[count_large];
  dest[count_small+1] = source[count_large+1];
  dest[count_small+2] = source[count_large+2];
}
```

Not clean but it got the job done.